# Recognising whether a method is written in Python or Cython

Tags: python, cython

I have a function which receives a method. I would like to recognise whether this method is written in Python or in Cython. Is there some reliable way to do this?

Comment: Why does this matter?

Comment: I'm interfacing with the symbolics module in Sage. This only works with methods written in pure Python. I need to determine whether I need to wrap the method.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the way / kind of wrapping you are applying to your methods and Sage? Just curious...

Comment: I'm not doing anything that special. Just calling this:

    x = var('x')
    function(name, x, evalf_func=f)

Where name is just a string and f is the method I receive. This gives an error when f is a method written in Cython.

Comment: hmm, comments aren't really suited for adding code fragments, but to sample consists of two lines of code.

Comment: Couldn't you just put a `try/except` around the code that causes the error and then deal with condition properly when it arises? This is know as [EAFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAFP#Exceptions) and considered very "Pythonic".

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought but, assuming that "pure Python" means "not built-in" where `the term “built-in” means “written in C”` (according to Python's documentation):

We could then distinguish those two kinds by doing:

```
>>> import types
>>> types.BuiltinFunctionType
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

*This is not C-compiled function :*

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     pass
>>> isinstance(foo, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
False
```

*This is C-compiled function :*

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> isinstance(array, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
True
```

So any third-party module with C extensions will also report its functions as type `builtin_function_or_method`.

Related link:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html

**EDIT :**

Another idea (a dirty one, but as Sage is not cooperative...):

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     pass
>>> foo.some_attr = 0
```

is accepted, while:

```
>>> array.some_attr = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'some_attr'
```

Hoping this can be helpful... You tell me.

Comment: In Sage both methods written in Python as those written in Cython appear to have type 'instancemethod'.

Comment: Another thing I was thinking about is that a pure Python would allow adding to it a new attribute, when a built-in one would throw an `AttributeError` exception... Yeah, this is ugly...